# Strange icon for Skype in system tray

Tags: icons, skype, system-tray

When I start Skype the following icon appears in the system tray [image] . Skype works fine and also if I click on the icon in the system tray, it is expanded to the full menu as usual. At some random time the icon changes to the usual green bubble with white checkmark. What's wrong?

PS: I am running Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: I am new to Linux ... how can I find out?

Comment: Unity looks like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/Ubuntu_13.04_Desktop.png), Gnome looks like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/GNOME-Shell-3.10.png).   :-)   and Unity is usually the default.

Comment: Then I am using Unity :-) Btw. how can I change?

Comment: [This](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=988151) might help *(I forgot my Ubuntu One thing, so I can't see the flippin' pictures)*. Have you installed anything or removed something? It just might not be able to find the icon file.

Comment: If youd do not mind messing around with it a bit, you could reinstall it using `sudo apt-get rmeove skype`, `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get install skype`. **This might muck up any configuration etc that you have added**.

Comment: I am not sure whether I have installed or removed something which could have affected Skype :-) But I think not ... What is strange is that after some time the icon recovers its usual form so apparently it does find the icon file.

Comment: I meant `apt-get remove...` in my previous comment. I like the purpose of Skype, it just can be SO annoying. So has the icon reappeared yet?

Comment: Today the icon has been working fine right from the beginning ... as I said, what is really strange is the fact that the problems seem to appear according to some random mechanism!?